# Send file is done but actually fail in Asmack android

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, asmack

This is how I try to send a file over XMPP using `asmack` lib ([from the GtalkSms project](http://code.google.com/r/fschmaus-gtalksms/source/browse/)) and a Ejabberd server:

```
//Configure provider in onCreate()
 configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());

// Configure function
private void configure(ProviderManager pm){
    pm.addIQProvider("si","http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("open","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("close","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());
}

// This is how I send file after login to server (I put everything below in a 
function, inside a Thread and call thread.start() at the end of function):

// set the serviceDiscoveryManager
ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConn);
if (sdm == null){
    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(xmppConn);
}
sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

 // Create the file transfer manager
 FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
 FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
 OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager
                    .createOutgoingFileTransfer(Receiver
                            + "@MyDomain");
 transfer.sendFile(new File(myFilePath), "myDescription");
```

If I use another client to test the file transfer  (http://coccinella.im/), then I can chat and send a file over my Ejarbberd server between (2 coccinella clients). If I use a coccinella client and my client in android, I can chat between them and I can receive file sent from coccinella client to my android client. However, when I try to send file from my android client to the coccinella client, `transfer.isDone()` always returns `true` and `transfer.getStatus() == Status.error` also returns `true`.

So what's happen to my Android client? Did I use wrong library? Or I missed something?

**Edited:** This is what I got from debugger: `<iq id="QgJIb-29" to="phuocdh@localhost/Smack" from="phuoctest@localhost/Coccinella@phuocdh-pc" type="error"><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost></streamhost></query></error></iq>`

Comment: @Flow: If I use `smack.jar` and `smackx.jar` instead of `asmack.jar`, can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/aSmack-XMPP-File-Transfer

Comment: @Flow: I edited my question, can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: Thanks you flow! I solved this problem with your new library!!

Comment: You should then answer your question and mark it as answered. Make sure to add all the information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @Kingfisher,
have you use this blog
http://harryjoy.com/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire/
to send file ?
and which smack lib you finally using ?

Comment: @Kingfisher if you got solution than you can help me, my chat app with ejabberd server and between android clients working properly but when i send any file than the progress of sending stucks at 0.0..what could be the reason?

Comment: @Devang You should use newest version of `asmack`, and config Ejabberd server to support file transfer